# Adding UITableView Delegate to my ViewController Causing an Incomplete Implementation Error

Tags: iphone, ios

Adding UITableView Delegate to my ViewController Causing an Incomplete Implementation Error

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyClassViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    UITableView*  _tableView;

}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITableView* tableView;

@end
```

and in my .m file

```
@implementation PopUpPlaylistViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@interface MyClassViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you implement these protocols, and they have required methods. see the documentation for both of them to see what methods are required and which are optional.